# Java custom serialization with compression for low network bandwidth use

Tags: java, serialization, glassfish, compression, ejb

I am currently developing a client/server application. The application server is Glassfish v3, the communication is by remote EJBs. The main problem is the heavy network bandwidth use when serializing objects graphs. For example in the next method:

```
@Stateless
public class MyEJB extends MyRemoteInterface {

   @Override
   public PurchaseOrder savePurchaseOrder( PurchaseOrder po ) { ... }

}
```

this method, when invoked remotely, will receive a PurchesOrder instance which is a object graph that when is transferred over the network it will take a lot of KB, the same when it returns.

I have manage this, for now, changing the prototype of the method like this:

```
...

   @Override
   public byte[] savePurchaseOrder( byte[] po ) { ... }

...
```

I manually de/compress and de/serialize the PurchaseOrder instance before and after transferring it over the network. But I loose type safe methods and it gets ugly.

Is there a way to use java custom serialization for compressing the output stream in the default serialization process? for example:

```
    @Entity
    public class PurchaseOrder implements Serializable {

       private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
           // default serialization 
           oos.defaultWriteObject();

           // COMPRESS STREAM HERE (zip or gzip)
       }

       private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) 
           throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

           // DECOMPRES STREAM HERE 

           // default deserialization
           ois.defaultReadObject();
       }

    }
```

I need the code of "DE/COMPRESS STREAM HERE" part, or another good idea.

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Xavier.

Comment: Others have already given you good answers. However, keep in mind that if you change the signature to return a byte[] instead of an instance you may actually increase the need for bandwidth. Normal serialization will tag object instances so that they are sent once and then referred to. If you have duplicates (which might not be a problem for you in this case) you will lose that with a byte[].

Comment: yes, I don't whant to use byte[] in the signature, that's why I'm looking to automatically compress the object inside the default serialization process.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions here for using custom serialization are good, but can be a lot of work depending on your objects.  you could use generics and a wrapper class to get a "somewhat" nicer implementation.

a "simple" implementation could look like:

```
public class ShrinkWrap<E> implements Serializable
{
  private transient E _value;

  public ShrinkWrap(E value) { _value = value; }

  public E get() { return _value; }

  private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
    // default serialization 
    oos.defaultWriteObject();

    // compress _value to a byte[] using new ObjectOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()))
    byte[] compValue = ...;

    oos.writeInt(compValue.length);
    oos.write(compValue);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    // default deserialization
    ois.defaultReadObject();

    byte[] compValue = new byte[ois.readInt()];
    ois.readFully(compValue);

    // decompress _value from byte[] using new ObjectInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream()))
    _value = ...;
  }
}
```

Comment: sounds good, but just a question: in the writeObject method, does the oos won't have duplicated data? one compressed and one not compressed? as you first write values with oos.defaultWriteObject(), but then you write to it compValue ?

Comment: @XavierCallejas - oops, good point, missed the transient.  updated now.  in this example, you don't really need the defaultRead/WriteObject calls.  you could make the ShrinkWrap Externalizable instead of Serializable.

Comment: the line coul you check the line: byte[] compValue = ois.readInt(); the int value cannot be assigned to the byte[].

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you need supply a custom factory that is capable of compressing/decompressing the stream automatically

Try having a read of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/socketfactory/index.html

Comment: I suggest you use a link from Java 7.

Comment: do you know if this will work with a EJB application, running Glassfish ?

Comment: I've personally never done it, but from what I've read, J2EE uses RMI as part of it's core implementation, to all programs to call into without having to go through HTTP, so yes, I'm sure it's doable, as to weather it's worth the hassle, is another question

Answer (score 0):

You can use DeflatorOutputStream and InflatorInputStream to compress the stream.

If you can I would suggest using a more compact serialization format such as JSon, or Exernalizable or your own binary format.  This is because default Java Serialization is relatively verbose. e.g. one Integer uses over 80 bytes.

Comment: I want to use the oos.defaultWriteObject() method because I do not want customize every entity class my project has (about more than 100), the default method it is fine for me, I just want to include compression to the stream.

Comment: can you help me with some code lines inside the writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) method? I need to use oos.defaultWriteObject();

Answer (score 0):

I think god idea is using `ZipOutputStream and ZipInputStream`. You might choose level of compression object and send multiple object in one file.

Comment: Yes, I am using ZipOuputStream outside the writeObject method, but how can I use it inside it reusing the ObjectOutputStream instance parameter? can you help me completing the code where it says // COMPRESS STREAM HERE .. ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JBoss Serialization](https://www.jboss.org/serialization), It's worth a look and maybe help you lot.